# Wix (VS installer) - missing editors toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

Wix 3.10 is installed on my PC. extension to visual studio 2015. 
I created a setup project based on Wix (which works).
On a setup project, usually there are some icons, setup tools (file system, registry, UI, costume actions...), but they are currently missing.

You can see these icons on any tutorial for Wix (like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoFPyIbcqN8)

How can I add them?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I got bit by the same video, It was the first hit in Bing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You can see these icons on any tutorial for Wix

That's not correct. The icons described in the video are from Add-In Express's [Designer for WiX Toolset](https://www.add-in-express.com/wix-designer/index.php). To add the icons, visit their website and install their product.